# Rails Server: more verbosity

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Are there any options I can run with

```
rails server
```

to print even more output about the rails processes to the console?

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend checking out [MiniProfiler](https://github.com/SamSaffron/MiniProfiler/tree/master/Ruby). It will provide a much more in-depth view of what's going on under the hood in Rails.

Comment: this is nice, but it would be nicer if it could show more than the view files. I would like to see controller actions/file names and model stuff as well.

Comment: the link is dead

Answer (score 2):

You can find all the options you can run with rails server in here.

[link to server.rb @github](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/commands/server.rb)

In case, you want to debug something I would recommend using the debugger or installing pry.

Comment: This link is dead.

Comment: this link is not working, should be reviewed.

Comment: Probably moved here https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/railties/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb

Answer (score -1):

The short answer is no. Rails server will already show all the information that is being appended into the server log. You can add things into the server log in your application using rails logging if you would like to see more information.